# Program Stopping while Executing(Files Handling)

Tags: c

I am trying to make a text file containing my Name, DOB & Address. I am trying to write to the file & then open it again to display the information.
Heres what i got.
The program is stopping during execution.

```
int main()
{
FILE *f1;
char name,dob,addr;
printf("INFORMATION\n\n\n");

f1=fopen("DATA.txt","w");
printf("Name        DOB        Address")  ;
fscanf(stdin,"%s %s %s",name,dob,addr);

fclose(f1);

fprintf(stdout,"\n\n");
f1=fopen("DATA.txt","r");
fscanf(f1,"%s %s %s",name,dob,addr);
fprintf(stdout,"%s %s %s",name,dob,addr);

fclose(f1);

return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read the data using the function fscanf from the file stdin, which refers to the terminal & it is then written to the file than is being pointed to by the file pointer f1. After closing the file DATA, I am again reopening it for reading. The data from the file along with the information in it is written to the file stdout, which refers to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

```
fscanf(stdin,"%s %s %s",name,dob,addr);
```

You have undefined behavior since you are scanning a character using `%s` format specifier . You should have a char array

```
char name[20];
char dob[10];
char addr[15];
```

Edits:

```
f1=fopen("DATA.txt","r");
```

You should open the file in write mode if you want to write something to file , opening the file in read mode and writing to a file is not valid.

Comment: ...and you must not try to write to a file if you opened it in read only mode.

Comment: @haccks Yes this was my first pasrsing observation will update it

Comment: I have one more query.
The DATA file I created does not contain the information.
How can i make the DATA.txt file contain my Information ?

Comment: @DriggyBoy If I get your problem read from stdin and write to your file using `fprintf()` make sure you open file in `w ` mode

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in fact, mainly

1. You declare `name`, `dob` and `address` as `char` they should be at least `char` arrays.
2. You don't check if the file was actually created (opened for writing).
3. You don't check that `fscanf()` did read the three strings.
4. You never write the data to the file.

This is the code, with all these issues fixed

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f1;
    char name[11], dob[11], addr[32];
    printf("INFORMATION\n\n\n");

    f1 = fopen("DATA.txt","w");
    if (f1 == NULL) /* suppose you don't have write */
        return -1;  /* access in this directory!
                     * always check this...
                     */
    printf("Name        DOB        Address\n")  ;

    /* check that scanf did read 3 values */
    if (fscanf(stdin, "%10s %10s %31s", name, dob, addr) == 3)
    {                /* ^ add this to prevent overflowing the buffers */
        /* You never write the data into the file */
        fprintf(f1, "%s %s %s", name, dob, addr);
    }
    fclose(f1);

    fprintf(stdout,"\n\n");

    f1 = fopen("DATA.txt","r");
    if (f1 == NULL) /* again check that the file was opened */
        return -1;

    if (fscanf(f1, "%10s %10s %31s", name, dob, addr) == 3)
        fprintf(stdout, "\n\n%s %s %s\n", name, dob, addr);

    fclose(f1);

    return 0;
}
```

i have anotated the problems with comments, hope this helps.